# Oozie shell action randomly throws syntax error

Tags: shell, hadoop, oozie

I have an oozie shell action scheduled to run everyday which executes some hive commands and outputs result to stdoutput to get captured by other actions.
But the shell action randomly fail with syntax error some days and successful other days.

Any help would be appreciated!

*Shellscript.sh*

```
    #!/bin/sh
ctr=0
loop=3
while [[ -z $personahistmaxdate  ||  -z $offeritemdimmaxdate  ||  -z $stgfirstgamedatemaxdate ]] && [[ ${ctr} -lt ${loop} ]];
do 
echo $ctr
personahistmaxdate=$(hive -e 'use identity; show partitions persona_hist;'|awk -F'|' '{print substr($1,length($1)-9, 10)}'|tail -1)
echo "personahistmaxdate=$personahistmaxdate"

offeritemdimmaxdate=$(hive -e 'use offer_item; show partitions offer_item_dim;'|awk -F'|' '{print substr($1,length($1)-9, 10)}'|tail -1)
echo "offeritemdimmaxdate=$offeritemdimmaxdate"

stgfirstgamedatemaxdate=$(hive -e 'use shooter_taxonomy_stg; show partitions stg_firstgamedate;'|awk -F'|' '{print substr($1,length($1)-9,10)}'|tail-1)
echo "stgfirstgamedatemaxdate=$stgfirstgamedatemaxdate"

 ctr=`expr $ctr + 1`
done

##Script to Handle if any of the variables is null then exit the shell

if [[ -z $personahistmaxdate  ||  -z $offeritemdimmaxdate  ||  -z $stgfirstgamedatemaxdate ]]
 then
echo "empty date in one of the variables"
exit 1
fi
```

**Oozie Log error**

```
stderr logs
./showpartitions.sh: 17: [[: not found
./showpartitions.sh: 17: -z: not found
./showpartitions.sh: 17: -z: not found
./showpartitions.sh: 23: [[: not found
./showpartitions.sh: 23: -z: not found
./showpartitions.sh: 23: -z: not found
```

Comment: It fails when you run it with `sh` and works when you run it with `bash`. Your script uses bash specific features, so you should change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash` (and make sure there are no spaces in front of it) and avoid running `sh yourscript`